# Why is my segue not firing?

Tags: ios, xml, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

After scanning all the threads on this topic, none of the advice has resolved the issue. Strangely enough, this problem only suddenly surfaced for what seems like no apparent reason. It worked fine last night.

Navigation is basically:

```
                   /-Navigation Controller -> View -> View (this last connection doesn't fire. Pushing the "next" button results in nothing.
                  /
TabBarController ---- Navigation Controller -> View -> View (works)
                 \
                  \
                   \-Same as above. (works)
```

As far as I can tell, the setups are identical, and I've gone through the busy work of deleting / cleaning / and re-constructing the troubled view and connection without success.

Here is the (hopefully) relevant section from my storyboard's XML

```
       <!--TDC2-->
    <scene sceneID="ing-Ye-PVs">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="dNt-CQ-X0M" customClass="TDC2" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ZIK-gx-Nq4">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="320" height="460"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="line" placeholder="Trip Number" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xbU-au-gtQ">
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="43" id="iMS-ez-xo8"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" keyboardType="numberPad"/>
                            <connections>
                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="dNt-CQ-X0M" id="DU2-gu-IxO"/>
                            </connections>
                        </textField>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="line" placeholder="Departure" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="B5M-Ti-5nL">
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="43" id="aUt-lR-eT8"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                            <connections>
                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="dNt-CQ-X0M" id="XyV-Of-fnR"/>
                            </connections>
                        </textField>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="line" placeholder="Out Fuel" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yxx-QE-lRo">
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="43" id="i11-f6-Kco"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                            <connections>
                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="dNt-CQ-X0M" id="SPC-XB-pOD"/>
                            </connections>
                        </textField>
                        <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="line" placeholder="Start Hobbs" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wAx-ux-6y5">
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="43" id="la9-aF-SWs"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" keyboardType="numberPad"/>
                            <connections>
                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="dNt-CQ-X0M" id="4UI-cl-zxC"/>
                            </connections>
                        </textField>
                        <segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="plain" selectedSegmentIndex="0" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PXM-z4-ndS">
                            <segments>
                                <segment title="PIC"/>
                                <segment title="SIC"/>
                            </segments>
                        </segmentedControl>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Who is flying?" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="frD-Qe-Ib9">
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Trip" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Fuc-2m-9Zy">
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="30" id="7cK-5c-HM9"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Depart" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uvI-4w-aME">
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Fuel" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fY7-7H-utj">
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Hobbs" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WI2-MH-Xfw">
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <gestureRecognizers/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="fY7-7H-utj" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="yxx-QE-lRo" secondAttribute="centerY" type="default" id="33E-Ci-sZT"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="4YK-YK-l5r"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="fY7-7H-utj" firstAttribute="baseline" secondItem="yxx-QE-lRo" secondAttribute="baseline" type="default" id="4eX-Xh-6rd"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="wAx-ux-6y5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="yxx-QE-lRo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="4pq-KW-vdv"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xbU-au-gtQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="6Dc-8Z-L4q"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="yxx-QE-lRo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="7HV-va-Jwi"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="Fuc-2m-9Zy" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZIK-gx-Nq4" secondAttribute="leading" constant="42" id="90D-A5-UCb"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="frD-Qe-Ib9" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="PXM-z4-ndS" secondAttribute="centerX" type="default" id="9Df-Ov-WRu"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="frD-Qe-Ib9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="wAx-ux-6y5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="ERP-rE-3ih"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="yxx-QE-lRo" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="Ibi-pB-iAX"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="WI2-MH-Xfw" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="wAx-ux-6y5" secondAttribute="centerY" type="default" id="JXF-d6-wg8"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PXM-z4-ndS" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="K0y-pX-ZFf"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="wAx-ux-6y5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="WI2-MH-Xfw" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="P6r-KM-Uj7"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="Fuc-2m-9Zy" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="xbU-au-gtQ" secondAttribute="centerY" type="default" id="RhF-sp-4Ru"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="xbU-au-gtQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" secondAttribute="leading" type="default" id="Rx5-ms-1N7"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wAx-ux-6y5" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="Tth-zq-zVg"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="PXM-z4-ndS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZIK-gx-Nq4" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="Z1c-rB-axa"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="Fuc-2m-9Zy" firstAttribute="baseline" secondItem="xbU-au-gtQ" secondAttribute="baseline" type="default" id="aU1-zo-HBe"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="xbU-au-gtQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZIK-gx-Nq4" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="e3G-YD-OOE"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="wAx-ux-6y5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="yxx-QE-lRo" secondAttribute="leading" type="default" id="fpp-at-Fis"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="yxx-QE-lRo" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fY7-7H-utj" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="ifT-MI-4hR"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="xbU-au-gtQ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="jNt-zD-oTI"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="uvI-4w-aME" firstAttribute="baseline" secondItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" secondAttribute="baseline" type="default" id="kmY-Ol-p7p"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="yxx-QE-lRo" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="B5M-Ti-5nL" secondAttribute="leading" type="default" id="mI4-Zu-iNP"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="PXM-z4-ndS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="frD-Qe-Ib9" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="qGW-ek-yZd"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="uvI-4w-aME" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZIK-gx-Nq4" secondAttribute="top" constant="81" id="uaR-8Y-5QN"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="xbU-au-gtQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Fuc-2m-9Zy" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="ujE-gd-4M9"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="uvI-4w-aME" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZIK-gx-Nq4" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="w3k-jd-ax9"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="2nj-Ip-nf5">
                    <barButtonItem key="leftBarButtonItem" title="Back" id="tVS-8H-FUI"/>
                    <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" title="Next" id="1JK-F2-zOK"/>
                </navigationItem>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="departure" destination="B5M-Ti-5nL" id="AWa-Ws-aD3"/>
                    <outlet property="outFuel" destination="yxx-QE-lRo" id="K6r-M4-Rlz"/>
                    <outlet property="startHobbs" destination="wAx-ux-6y5" id="Dyn-O8-9Hh"/>
                    <outlet property="tripNumber" destination="xbU-au-gtQ" id="AZA-T4-Izz"/>
                    <outlet property="whosFlying" destination="PXM-z4-ndS" id="VKX-zm-stJ"/>
                    <segue destination="VZ0-Ck-hG8" kind="push" id="pCS-hs-xSz"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Gtn-Vk-tyE" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1133" y="740"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="6on-A1-vuU">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="VZ0-Ck-hG8" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="YmM-zs-zBh">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="320" height="460"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="g9K-Xz-a2H"/>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="UYI-Pa-J93" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1670" y="745"/>
    </scene>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing in the code you posted that's useful for diagnosing your problem. You might try adding an action method to this "next" button (in addition to the segue that's presumably connected to it), and see if that fires.

Comment: You could also post the XML from the storyboard, would probably be more helpful since that is where you are having the problem.

Comment: I've added the relevant parts of my XML.

I cannot add an action, because my NavController is not auto-populating my view in the editor with the navBar for some reason.